# Please give us the ability to sort "featured" tab by bounty amount

Tags: feature-request, bounties, sorting, bountied-tab

The "featured" tab currently lists questions with open bounties, sorted by the time left until the bounty expires.  Could we also add the ability to sort by largest bounty?  Sometimes I'm looking for best bang for my buck, and there are so many open bounties on SO that it fills more than one page.

Comment: More users have [that desire](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/247523/364217), myself included.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

We recently changed the featured page to **give larger bounties a higher sort** (and the larger the bounty, the stronger the effect) as I mentioned here:

https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/09/bounty-reasons-and-post-notices/

However, for the last 24 hours, the sort order reverts to strictly descending time of expiration, ala eBay.

Comment: thanks, but i'm not sure how much this helps on stack overflow, where there are 7 pages of bounties, so approximately the whole first page is filled with bounties expiring in <24 hours

Comment: Agreed with @Kip... a question with a bounty of 500 rep should *definitely* show up on the top of the list. Always.

Comment: Give option to Sort with: [Expiring "ASC"| "DESC"]&&[BOUNTY "ASC"| "DESC"]

Comment: This is borderline a bug/broken.  At minimum a 500 bounty should always appear at the top.  It's been 4 yrs this is broken.

Answer (score 10):

As proposed in comments already, and inspired by [a post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/288069/993547) on Meta StackOverflow:

Please make the bounty list sorted descending by offered bounty. Always. I really have to go the entire list to see a 500 reputation bounty somewhere in the middle of the pack.

If a bounty is some kind of advertisement, why not reward a higher pay by more prominence. If you want to show your ad during the final of a soccer match, you pay double. I think you should be rewarded the same 'quality' when putting a bounty on a question.

Answer (score 7):

I've created a userscript that allows you to sort bounties by their amount (smallest-to-largest or largest-to-smallest).

[image]
[image]

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name         Sort by bounty amount
// @namespace    http://stackexchange.com/users/4337810/%E1%94%95%E1%96%BA%E1%98%8E%E1%95%8A
// @version      1.0
// @description  Allows you to sort by bounty amount
// @author       ᔕᖺᘎᕊ (http://stackexchange.com/users/4337810/%E1%94%95%E1%96%BA%E1%98%8E%E1%95%8A)
// @match        *://*.stackexchange.com/*
// @match        *://*.stackoverflow.com/*
// @match        *://*.superuser.com/*
// @match        *://*.serverfault.com/*
// @match        *://*.askubuntu.com/*
// @match        *://*.stackapps.com/*
// @match        *://*.mathoverflow.net/*
// @grant        none
// ==/UserScript==
if($('.bounty-indicator').length) { //if there is at least one bounty on the page
    $('.question-summary').each(function() {
        bountyAmount = $(this).find('.bounty-indicator').text().replace('+', '');
        $(this).attr('data-bountyamount', bountyAmount); //add a 'bountyamount' attribute to all the questions
    });

    if ($('#question-mini-list').length) { //if on homepage featured tab
        var $wrapper = $('#question-mini-list');
    } else {
        var $wrapper = $('#questions'); //if on questions featured tab
    }

    setTimeout(function() {
        //filter buttons:
        $('.subheader').after('<span>sort by bounty amount:&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</span><span id="largestFirst">largest first&nbsp;&nbsp;</span><span id="smallestFirst">smallest first</span>');

        //Thanks: http://stackoverflow.com/a/14160529/3541881
        $('#largestFirst').css('cursor', 'pointer').on('click', function() { //largest first
            $wrapper.find('.question-summary').sort(function(a, b) {
                return +b.getAttribute('data-bountyamount') - +a.getAttribute('data-bountyamount');
            }).prependTo($wrapper);
        });

        //Thanks: http://stackoverflow.com/a/14160529/3541881
        $('#smallestFirst').css('cursor', 'pointer').on('click', function() { //smallest first
            $wrapper.find('.question-summary').sort(function(a, b) {
                return +a.getAttribute('data-bountyamount') - +b.getAttribute('data-bountyamount');
            }).prependTo($wrapper);
        });
    }, 500);
}
```

The main limitation of this is that it can only sort what is on the current page (I don't use the API), there may be higher bounties on a different page :( But it works on smaller sites than SO where there are not 384 bounties on at the same time!

**To use it**, please install my [SE Optional Features userscript at StackApps](https://stackapps.com/questions/6091/se-additional-optional-features) to which I have added this to.

Answer (score 3):

As others have asked, please make the bounty list able to be unconditionally sorted by offered bounty.

There are currently nine pages of bounty questions on SO. This is part of the last page, and it can be seen that questions with offered bounties of 100 and 200 are listed here instead of appearing on the first page. These questions appear later than those offering 50, even though the latter will not expire for 7 days:

[image]

I agree it's useful to highlight soon-to-expire bounties, per @Jeff Atwood's answer. However, instead of making the bounty sort dependent on expiration time, I'd prefer a separate sort on expiration time. Make that the default sort.

As a variation on this, if it's too much effort technically to add different sorts at this sub-level of bounties, perhaps we can at least have a pair of radio buttons (`Expiring` and `All`). Or even a separate "tab" for each of these two at the higher level.

One way or another, please make it possible to sort the entire list in descending bounty order.