# How do you order the featured questions by their bounty score?

Tags: discussion, bounties

I think they are ordered by soonest expiration date, but I want to see them ordered by their bounty score.

Comment: The answer to "how" is currently [you can't](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7753/please-give-us-the-ability-to-sort-featured-tab-by-bounty-amount), but if you'd like this ability please vote up the linked feature request.