# Why is my question with bounty not in the featured tab?

Tags: support, bounties, bountied-tab

I have put a bounty on [one of my questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3987532/where-does-zend-form-fit-in-the-model-view-controller-paradigma), however I don't see it appear in the [Featured tab](https://stackoverflow.com/?tab=featured) (also not when I'm not logged in).

Why is this. Aren't all bounty questions supposed to be visible there?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As indicated over [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7753/please-give-us-the-ability-to-sort-featured-tab-by-bounty-amount), the sorting of the Featured tab is by the time left.

Since you posted the bounty at 16:09 UTC and it has only been roughly 2 hours since then, it still has a lot of time left. As of writing this answer, I found it on the last page of the full list, near the bottom but not at it.

The front page sort, unlike the Questions list, is cut short when it reaches the maximum for one page. You'll find at the bottom the following line:

> Looking for more featured questions? Browse the [complete list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions?sort=featured).

As such, as long as you aren't on the first page of featured questions, you won't be on the front page listing. You'll still be present in the full listing, as well as on the short lists of anyone who search by tags.

Comment: Yeh, the front page sort really needs pagination.

Comment: Additionally, there appears to be a bit of caching, so questions don't always appear *immediately*.

Answer (score 0):

But I see it under featured... search for [mvc] and then click the featured tab.

Comment: There I see it too, but I don't see it on the normal featured tab (http://stackoverflow.com/?tab=featured)?

Comment: It's there, on page 6: http://stackoverflow.com/questions?page=6&sort=featured