# Why doesn't my bountied question show in "Featured"?

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, bounties

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why is my question with bounty not in the featured tab?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/68559/why-is-my-question-with-bounty-not-in-the-featured-tab)

I have a fairly complicated question open on SO at the moment, and it's not attracting too many views or responses. I added a generous bounty, expecting it to appear on the "Featured" tab. According to the Stack Overflow FAQ:

> Slice off anywhere from +50 to +500 of your own hard-earned reputation and attach it to any question as a bounty. The bountied question will appear with a special indicator in all question lists, and **it will also be visible on the home page Featured tab for the duration of the bounty period**.

My question is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4007378/upgrade-path-for-legacy-reporting-embedded-access-2003) and it clearly shows there is an open bounty, **but it doesn't appear on the feature tab**.

Any reason why? One of the reasons I put the bounty was for the extra views the question would get on the feature tab, but this seems to be a waste now.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/68559/why-is-my-question-with-bounty-not-in-the-featured-tab

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[rchern](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/140548/rchern) [found it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/68559/why-is-my-question-with-bounty-not-in-the-featured-tab) - the featured page is sorted by bounty time remaining.