# Is there any way to sort bounty questions?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, bounties, sorting, bountied-tab

How to sort recent bounty questions in Stack Exchange sites? I can't see a way to sort questions in the featured-tab. Am I missing something?

Any option to sort bounty questions in ascending and descending order? Why don't we give an option to sort bounty questions?

Comment: They are sorted by age - the oldest first. What other kinds of sorts do you need (seeing as there are not that many bounties at any one time)?

Comment: Instead of giving an option to sort bounty questions on featured page, I would like to have an option to [search bounty questions](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/68253/187824) via advanced search. (Multiple benefits in single implemented feature and easier to implement)

Comment: What would you want to sort them by? Bounty Start Date? End Date? Amount? Something else?

Comment: @hims056 we can search questions with bounties, see [this](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=hasnotice%3A1+is%3Aquestion+locked%3A0+lastactive%3A2013-10-03..2013-10-10) - not 100% and you have to put the dates manually (to filter out questions with historic lock) but it returns "only" 25 false positives at the moment. :)

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd - Wow really great use of advanced search. May be worth to add it [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/54476/187824) too.

Comment: @hims056 [done](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/200242/152859). :)

Comment: See my answer for a script to do this: http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/252238/260841