# Add sorting by bounty size to new navigation

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, bounties, sorting, new-nav

The new nav has a special 'sort' option now. Can we have a 'bounty amount' added to these options? Please?

So it would look like this:

[image]

Note: [This question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7753/please-give-us-the-ability-to-sort-featured-tab-by-bounty-amount) is asking for the same thing, but with the new nav, this should be incredibly easy to add!!

Comment: Indeed. This should finally be implemented!

Comment: Related bug to this newly implemented feature: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/263828/what-is-the-bounty-size-sort-actually-sorting-by-in-new-nav

Comment: @Taryn Has this feature been removed again?