# What is the "bounty size" sort actually sorting by in new nav?

Tags: bug, status-norepro, sorting, new-nav

When visiting the bounty list with the new navigation, I attempted to sort by the "bounty size". My sort selection looks like this:

[image: Bounty Sort]

The expectation is that this will return a list of bounties sorted either highest to lowest or lowest to highest (I'm not picky) across all available bounties.

The actual returned list is a sorted list of bounties sorted by size from highest to lowest **PER RESULT PAGE**.

For example, [page one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/need-answers?show=bounties&sort=size) (50 questions per page) of the bounties returns this:

[image: Page 1 results]

**Page 8**, returns this:

[image: Page 8]

I would expect everything on page 8 that had a bounty of 150 or higher to have appeared in my page one results.

**Update after new-new nav release**:

The bug is still present.

[Page 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/bounties/size): https://i.stack.imgur.com/1z1pg.png,

[Page 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/bounties/size?page=2): https://i.stack.imgur.com/A85RQ.png

[Page 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/bounties/size?page=3): https://i.stack.imgur.com/3mIZC.png

Comment: Can you update the bug if it's still present in the new release?

Comment: The bug is still present @Sklivvz. [Page 1](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/bounties/size): http://i.imgur.com/cHzYFWg.png, [Page 2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/bounties/size?page=2): http://i.imgur.com/VbH4N6D.png [Page 3](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/bounties/size?page=3): http://i.imgur.com/HH0S4QN.png

Comment: Same for me ([Meta SO](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/308187/bounty-questions-not-ordered-by-size-properly)): still present

Comment: It seems fixed now.