# Can't deep link into specific question page on new-nav

Tags: bug, status-completed, new-nav

As I was filing [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/263828/what-is-the-bounty-size-sort-actually-sorting-by-in-new-nav) bug report, I wanted to provide deep links into specific bounty pages to demonstrate my issue. When utilizing the "permalink" option at the bottom of each page, I found that this isn't possible.

To demonstrate my issue, repeat the following steps:

- Go to a tag that has more than one page of questions. We'll use [python](/questions/tagged/python) ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/new/python?show=all&sort=newest)) for this example
- Scroll to the bottom and go to any page other than 1 and watch the address bar as the page loads.
- Notice the the address bar first loads [this](https://stackoverflow.com/?page=3&pagesize=50&tags=python) (with a page parameter)

  ```
  https://stackoverflow.com/?page=3&pagesize=50&tags=python
  ```

  Then redirects to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/new/python?show=all&sort=newest) (without a page parameter).

  ```
  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/new/python?show=all&sort=newest
  ```

*I got the link with the page parameter by right clicking on the "3" in the navigation and selecting "Save Link Location"*

If you select the "Permalink" at the bottom of the now loaded page 3, the page will reload to page one and the second link (without the parameter) will load:

```
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/new/python?show=all&sort=newest
```

Comment: Use the link before the redirection to hotlink?

Comment: That link is the same as the redirected one. The only way to get the deep link, that I can see, is via the method I used above. The URL bar shows, effectively, the same link on page one as page 3 - except for a very brief flicker right at page load.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has been fixed with one of the `2015.8.24.*` builds.